# Get All Controls in a UserControl in WPF

Tags: wpf, user-controls

i want to get all controls that has been added in xaml file like TextBox and other controls that inherit FrameworkElemnt.
i tried several ways but all of them found nothing.
i placed this codes in my UserControl Constructor after InitializeComponent()
1-
in this code this : VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(this) returns zero

```
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(this); i++)
        {
            Visual childVisual = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(this, i);
        }
```

2-
also this code returns nothing:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < this.VisualChildrenCount; i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = this.GetVisualChild(i);
        }
```

3-
because controls in xaml are defined as internal following code returns no element:

```
    var elements = typeof(Login).GetProperties( BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance )
        .Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(FrameWorkElement));
```

can any one give me a solution?

Comment: What do you want this for?

Comment: Take a look at the open source program "Snoop". It's able to inspect and enumerate every control in a WPF application, for the most part. You might be able to get insight from it. http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/

Comment: You need to show your XAML as well, there could be several reasons why you're not seeing what you expect to see.